# Spring 4 MVC Resteasy

Tags: spring-mvc, resteasy, spring-4

I am looking for a sample project with these requirements [Spring 4 MVC with resteasy]. But i couldn't find any solution with those requirement. Any idea about that should be helpful for me.

Answer (score 0):

I googled "Spring 4 MVC with resteasy", and there are a lot of useful links !

[resteasy-spring](https://dzone.com/articles/resteasy-spring)

[resteasy-spring-integration-example](https://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/resteasy-spring-integration-example/)

I hope these link help you.